# Detailed compiler warning settings in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compiler-warnings

How to change the detailed settings of the compiler warnings in Visual Studio? All I could find is the **"Warning levels"** property on the **"build" tab** of a project.

In particular, I'd like the VS to display **"Missing XML comments"** not only for public members, but also for internal and protected. Are such settings possible?

Comment: I assume you already have it displaying warnings for missing XML comments on *public* members? I'm not aware of a built-in way for VS to warn about missing comments on internal/protected/private members.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question but you can use an external tool, like [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis), to enforce coding guidelines like documenting all members, regardless of the fact it's public or not.

Maybe you can add it as a pre-build event, integrating the enforcement with your build process.

Comment: Trying StyleCop. It looks great! Thank you!